# How to calculate E^At for differential equations using mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I need help with my code.
I need to calculate E^At (differential equations).

This is my code for solvig the equation:

```
sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t]/2 - y[t] + 64*z[t], y'[t] == -y[t]/4 - 16*z[t], z'[t] == y[t] - z[t]/4, x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, z[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, t]
```

Also this is my matrix:

```
A = {{-1/2, -1, 64}, {0, -1/4, -16}, {0, 1, -1/4}} // MatrixForm
```

I'll be very thankful if you could provide me any help on how to approach this exercise. Thanks!!

Comment: [`MatrixExp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixExp.html).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = {{-1/2, -1, 64}, {0, -1/4, -16}, {0, 1, -1/4}};

X[t_] := {x[t], y[t], z[t]};

Eqns = Thread[D[X[t], t] == A.X[t]]

sol = DSolve[{Eqns, x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, z[0] == 0}, X[t], t]
```

Or just use `MatrixExp` as suggested in the comment.

Lets first extract the matrix `A` from the equations,

```
Eqns = {x'[t] == -x[t]/2 - y[t] + 64*z[t], y'[t] == -y[t]/4 - 16*z[t],
    z'[t] == y[t] - z[t]/4};

A = -CoefficientArrays[Eqns, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}][[2]] // Normal   

MatrixExp[A*t, {1, -1, 0}]
```